# Exposing multiple docker services over nginx

Tags: nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-location

I'm serving a website, generated by a docker container, using nginx, which also lives in a docker container. This setup works quite well.

What I want to do now, is serve multiple websites, from multiple containers.

My (simplified) setup is below.

```
http {

upstream app_01 {
    server container_01:80;
}

upstream app_02 {
    server container_02:80;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    include common.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/ssl.conf;

    location / {
        proxy_pass         http://app_01;
        proxy_redirect     off;
        include common_location.conf;
    }

    location /alternative {
        proxy_pass         http://app_02;
        proxy_redirect off;
        include common_location.conf;
    }
}
```

}

`common_location.conf` contains:

```
proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP           $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For     $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Proto   $scheme;
proxy_set_header    Host                $host;
proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Host    $server_name;
proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Port    $server_port;
```

My original website still works fine (container_01), and I can kinda access the second site (container_02); the starting page gets loaded partially. It appears that it keeps the `upload/` part in all links.

My question: how do I get this to work?

Answer (score 0):

Since nobody seems to be able to answer, I ended up using an alternative to nginx, which worked within ten minutes.

Comment: what is the alternative? how did you solve this?

Comment: I used Traefik, which worked out of the box.